# Laravel 5.0 Model::create() method creates two rows in one form request

Tags: php, model, laravel-5

When I fire **Product::create($request->all())** method it creates **two rows** in a table with the same values.

**Here is my Form.**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'product.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
<!-- Title Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Description Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'source']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Category Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category', 'Category:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('category', 'Test Cat', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- create Form -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Here is my store method**

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{

    Product::create($request->all());

    // $productTran = $request->only(['title', 'description']);
    // $productTran['product_id'] = $product->id;
}
```

**Here is my Product.php (Model)**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = ['category'];

}
```

**And here is my ProductRequest class**

```
class ProductRequest extends FormRequest {

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required'
    ];
}

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Does not happen to me. You must be calling it twice from somewhere, or have some other code in your project affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it exatly the way you do, and didn't happen to me.
I don't know if this have any relationship, but in your model, the fillable var you need to put ['title', 'description', 'category'] for working correctly.

Or, at less, ['title'] that is the only required value.
Why you don't put dd($request); and show us what is inside.